# SQL Server : create view with max and min datetime for each user

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a table of events in SQL Server with `Username` and `DateTime`.

I want to create a view that shows the first and the last `EventDateTime` of the day for each user. How can I do it?

```
Username | EventDateTime
John     | 2015-03-27 15:19
Ana      | 2015-03-27 15:10
John     | 2015-03-27 15:18
Ana      | 2015-03-27 15:36
Ana      | 2015-03-27 15:45
John     | 2015-03-27 15:06
```

Basically I want the view to return this data:

```
Username | FirstEventDateTime | LastEventDateTime
John     | 2015-03-27 15:06   | 2015-03-27 15:19
Ana      | 2015-03-27 15:10   | 2015-03-27 15:45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the user and the day:

```
SELECT  Username,
        MIN(EventDateTime) FirstEventDateTime,
        MAX(EventDateTime) LastEventDateTime
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Username,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),EventDateTime,112)
ORDER BY Username;
```

Comment: just a question.. why we want to group by `eventdatetime` ? just for information :)

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Because op wanted the first and last event per user per day